# I am trying to avoid adjusting ranges in VBA when I add new value to a table, so I've tried using a formula and it keeps giving me a runtime error "9"

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

***'This formula works great, but I do not want to go back and adjust the range every time I add new values to 'the table***

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_AfterUpdate()

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet13.Range("A124:A218"), Me.ComboBox5.Value) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "This is an incorrect Job Number"
   Me.ComboBox5.Value = ""
   Exit Sub
   End If
'Lookup values based on first control
   With Me
        .ComboBox8 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox5, Sheet13.Range("Lookup2"), 2, 0)
        '.TextBox6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox5), Sheet13.Range("Lookup2"), 2, 0)
        '.Reg4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Reg1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 4, 0)
        '.Reg5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Reg1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 5, 0)
        '.Reg6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Reg1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 6, 0)
   End With



End Sub
```

***'I tried this route and I keep getting a runtime error***

```
Private Sub ComboBox5_AfterUpdate()

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet13.ListObjects("Job_List_Table").ListColumns("Job #").DataBodyRange.Select, Me.ComboBox5.Value) = 0 Then
   MsgBox "This is an incorrect Job Number"
   Me.ComboBox5.Value = ""
   Exit Sub
   End If
'Lookup values based on first control
   With Me
        .ComboBox8 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.ComboBox5, Sheet13.Range("Lookup2"), 2, 0)
        '.TextBox6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.ComboBox5), Sheet13.Range("Lookup2"), 2, 0)
        '.Reg4 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Reg1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 4, 0)
        '.Reg5 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Reg1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 5, 0)
        '.Reg6 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(CLng(Me.Reg1), Sheet2.Range("Lookup"), 6, 0)
   End With



End Sub
```

Comment: You should not have `Select` in your expression.

Comment: That worked until I added values to the table and now when I try to run the macro, excel closes.

Comment: It's working now, not really sure what happened. Thanks again!